# Cost of using require.js in an existing project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs

I am planning to use requireJS in my project. But does that cost more work to add it to my existing project as i have a good number of js files already in my project. what is the easier way to rope in require js into my project?

Comment: More work than what? What is the other option, not to use require.js?

Comment: I have did coding the traditional way handling dependency checks and loading the scripts files manually. And now i wish to use requireJS @Bergi

Comment: i wish to know the amount of work we will need to put in  re write the ordinary js code require js compatible code

Comment: If you are already having (manual) dependency checks in your code, then your code shouldn't need too much restructuring and the workload should be small. We cannot know however without seeing your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

requireJS is good for avoiding unwanted scripts from loading.

if you think that your project has lot of Javascript files, that are loading unnecessarily, you can go for RequireJS. You can load the Javascript files in your page dynamically.

This will help you to reduce unwanted load in your application. This will also increase the speed of your application.

You need to add a define/require with the js files that are needed, a return at the end of each file. And you are done with 90% of code change. Your bigger part is calling the function of one file from another. You need to change them at most of the area in the code.